# Issue installing web application using tomcat6

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

I have a .war file of a web application. I installed the tomcat6 manager and i deployed the war file using that. But after that i am not able to get it running. I get a FAIL message saying FAIL - Application at context path /apnaPradesh could not be started. apnaPradesh is the deployed war filename.

Also i get the following exception registered in the logs.

> 18 Jul, 2010 4:34:59 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: HTMLManager: init:
>   Associated with Deployer
>   'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
>   18 Jul, 2010 4:34:59 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global
>   resources are available 18 Jul, 2010
>   4:34:59 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting
>   web application at '/apnaPradesh' 18
>   Jul, 2010 4:36:02 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Loading Spring root
>   WebApplicationContext 18 Jul, 2010
>   4:37:01 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception
>   sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/el/Logger  at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.(ClassUtils.java:41)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.feedStandardConfig(FacesConfigurator.java:138)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:115)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.initFaces(StartupServletContextListener.java:64)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:47)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1251)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:612)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.el.Logger  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
>   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
>   ... 25 more 18 Jul, 2010 4:37:01 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Closing Spring root
>   WebApplicationContext

I am beginner. Just got this war file and i am trying to install and check. So please help.

Answer (score 6):

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.el.Logger

Looks like a missing dependency in the war.

Check the tomcat/webapps/THEWEBAPP/WEB-INF/lib directory for commons-el.jar

Seems like that where the class exists.

Answer (score 1):

Download commons-el.jar from the following url 
 
http://commons.apache.org/el/download_el.cgi

After Unzipping the downloaded file you will find commons-el.jar. Put this into your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first identify the class-paths at the container (Tomcat) and application level. The class may not be IN the directory as a *.class file but in a JAR file.

The paths, conventionally are:

- lib
- webapps/YOUR_APP/WEB-INF/lib
- webapps/YOUR_APP/WEB-INF/classes

If you are using a UNIX-base FS, try in your tomcat home with:

- find . -name "*.jar"

Answer (score 0):

The app is deployed and working now! 
http://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ETHREEOH-819  link helped me. 
I just had to paste a copy of commons-el.jar to the app WEB-INF/lib directory.